# Import JSON file from JS file

Tags: javascript

I have a configuration object that I need to use in multiple files

```
const config = {test: true}
```

can I import the JSON and assign it directly to a variable or I need to create a new file and export a function that returns the object?

Comment: `export const config = {test: true}` and then `import { config } from "file.js"`

Comment: Ultimately, it all depends on if you want the object to be mutable. The different export methods serve different purposes: you could export the object itself and use it as-is; or export a function that returns an original copy of the object if you want to reset it each time it's used; or pass the object through [`Object#freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). With the current object, you could call `config.test = false` in any file that consumes it and potentially cause problems elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export it like this -

```
const config = { test: true }
export default config
```

and then you can simply import like this -

```
import config from "filePath"
```

Or you can include an actual JSON-File like this:

**config.json**

```js
{"test": true}
```

**app.js**

```js
const config = require('./config.json');
// Do your operations
```

Comment: ahh you are right! I don´t need a function. just export the object. thank you!

Comment: great it helped